# HTTP header field for URI deprecation/expiration

Tags: rest, version-control, http-headers

I'm building a REST service where I want to implement a way to deprecate certain URIs when they shouldn't be supported anymore for one reason or another. As functions are deprecated, they will be replaced by new ones that work in similar (but not identical) ways. This means that at some point, I will have to start responding with `410 Gone`.

The idea is that all client software should be updated, and after say six months all users should have had the chance to upgrade. At this time, the deprecated URIs will start to inform the client that it's out of date, so that the client can display a message to the user. This time is not known in advance, though, and can't explicitly be written in the documentation.

The problem I want to solve is:

**Is there an HTTP header field I should use to indicate that a certain URI will cease to work at a certain time and, if so, which?**

This can't be the first time someone wants to solve this problem. Is there an unofficial header field already in use, or should I design my own? Note that I don't want to add this information to the content itself, as that would mean that every resource was changed and needs to be refreshed by the client, which is of course not what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no. The resources should be driving your applications state, so if there is a change, the uri linking would provide the nessessary changes to your application.

For a HTTP header, you are free to add custom headers. Normally starting with X- but its important to know changes to uri's is only interesting to developers not users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In an ideal world, I think the resources could behave as you describe. However, I feel that in real life, developers could make mistakes and for example reveal information in ways that have unanticipated consequences. In this case, a resource might need to be completely removed and replaced with something that gives similar possibilities, but in a radically different way, to avoid exposing vulnerabilities. A static version of client could probably not be clever enough to figure out how that new representation works. That's why I need the possibility to deprecate.

Comment: By the way, what I'll probably end up doing is to use my own user-defined `Resource-Expires` header, with the same date format as `Expires`. However, you're incorrect about the `X-` prefix. It's been deprecated since [RFC 6648](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648).